# ActiveMQ: Monitor the state of a specific message (in .NET)

Tags: activemq-classic

Small question, say I queue a message into "ActiveMQ" queue, is there a way to know if the message was consumed or is still in the queue (from a .net environment)?

Can I query an "ActiveMQ" queue to know the current state of my message?

I'll try to give some more background, I pretty new with micro-services and am still trying to realize all the challenges that come with this type of architecture, so forgive me if my questions are trivial.

I'm working on building a system that would run "jobs" (whatever they would be) on a farm of distributed machines/nodes.

End users will be able to submit a "job" to a certain node or a group of nodes, a node needs to go through some preparation process before it can be executed.

I can use activemq queues to handle this pipeline but then i ask myself if i still need to maintain a database.

Say a user queues a job, i want to be able to assign a job id that will let the user know if his job was processed or is still waiting in the queue or queues....

What would be the best practice? Should i maintain both activemq queues for transferring messages between queues and a database to maintain the overall status of the job or can i stick with activemq only?

If activemq only, than how would i be able to tell the user the state of his job? If its waiting in a queue (or queues) or if it is processed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The biggest mistake new messaging users tend to make is to try and use the broker as a database.  The broker is great at reliably getting messages from point A to point B and that's how you should use it.  If you need to track state and keep statistics on jobs and their progress you are better served by using a database or some other storage to track that information.

If you need to let another system know when a message is processed the standard mechanism for that is request / reply where the processor of the message places a reply onto a response Queue you've created and have the sender listen for responses on that queue.